# How to use SAR TLVs for message concatenation in opensmppbox? Can it even be done?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, smpp, kannel, opensmppbox

From a cursory overview of the source code it seems that opensmppbox only supports message concatenation with UDH. Is it possible to make it understand messages concatenated with SAR TLVs? (i.e., `sar_msg_ref_num`, `sar_total_segments`, `sar_segment_seqnum`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your smsc config

```
group = smpp-tlv
name = sar_msg_ref_num
tag=0x020C
type= integer
length = 2

group = smpp-tlv
name = sar_total_segments
tag=0x020E
type= integer
length = 2

group = smpp-tlv
name = sar_segment_seqnum
tag=0x020F
type= integer
length = 2
```